# Как сделать многоязычность на сайте?

Tags: php

Пишу на php. Интересная не реализация, а сама **идея**.

Comment: от принципа реализацйии зависит много!

Comment: @myvzar, не стоит вознаграждать очками за хорошие ответы, особенно, пока у вас их мало. Лучше нажмите на "палец вверх" у хороших ответов. А когда получите исчерпывающую информацию, нажмите на галку у лучшего ответа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

для интерфейсных словечек удобно хранить в файле, как делает это например Opera да и очень много кто ещё. В выводе пишешь что-то типа:

```
<ul>
<li><?= __('main') ?></li>
<li><?= __('about') ?></li>
</ul>
```

А метод __() просто возвращает значение по ключу массива, который можно например в файл положить ru.php:

```
<?php

return array(
  'main' => 'Главная',
  'about' => 'О нас',
);
```

Comment: В принципе это иная реализация ini-файла, но вот за идею функции с именем `__` спасибо. Удобно (в смысле не только для этого).

Comment: идея не моя. Таким образом реализуется мультиязычность в моем любимом фреймворке kohana (kohanaframework.org)

Answer (score 0):

Определяешь по IP адресу клиента страну и на основании этих данных делаешь SELECT запрос к той части базы данных которая написана на нужном языке.

**Добавлено из комментария.**

Все элементы интерфейса можно перегнать в базу. Если это картинка, то храните в базе ссылки на нее на разных языках. Если кнопка, то храните ее надпись и.т.д. Потом внутри PHP скрипта делаете SELECT запрос. Перегоняете его результат в локальные  переменные скрипта и делаете интерфейс на основе значений этих переменных. Примерно так

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT foo");
// Обработка a
// Вывод элемента интерфейса
echo "<div id =foo type = button caption =" + $a + "</div>";
```

Comment: Я немножко не это имел в виду. Ну например для новостей можно создать различные таблицы в базе. А вот части интерфейса? Что с ними? Куда их? сохранять интерфейс кусками (на разных языках), или сохранять только слова которые нужно переводить?

Comment: Перенесено в ответ.

Comment: @igumnov, с картинками легче делать просто отдельные директории (с названиями, связанными с названиями языков) и просто подставлять в адрес.

Comment: > по IP адресу

Жесть! Есть же заголовок Accept-Language!

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, легче целиком сохранять переведённые интерфейсы.
То есть отдельные директории шаблонов под разные языки.
У Palmervan тоже хорошее решение. ИМХО, оно подходит, когда текста не очень много, и будет удобней моего.
А моё лучше, когда его много. Мне так кажется.